# How does web3.js decide to run a call() or sendTransaction() on a method call?

Tags: web3js

The [web3.js documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) states that with a contract method, call vs. transaction is chosen automatically:

> **Contract Methods**
>
> ```
> // Automatically uses call or sendTransaction based on the method type
> myContractInstance.myMethod(param1 [, param2, ...] [, ...]);
> ```

**edited for brevity*

I have tested two ways to call a function that does not mutate anything

1.`testInstance.testfunc(param1, {from:eth.accounts[0]})` 2.`testInstance.testfunc.call(param1)`

Events are being issued with option 1 only, so I know that web3.js is choosing `sendTransaction()`. I expected it to automatically choose a `call()`, because the function doesn't change any state.

How does web3.js determine which to use?

Comment: 1. It is a transaction, it can modify the contract state and generate events. The 'automagically determine' doesn't work sometimes. 2. It is a call it cannot modify contract state and will not generate events.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question; I think it is covered by Solidity `constant`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Web3.js you're using.

### Web3.js Stable

At version 0.19.0, web3 uses only the ABI constant keyword to decide whether to issue a `call()` or a `sendTransaction()`:

> ```
> SolidityFunction.prototype.execute = function () {
>     var transaction = !this._constant;
>
>     // send transaction
>     if (transaction) {
>         return this.sendTransaction.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
>     }
>
>     // call
>     return this.call.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
> };
> ```

~[source](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/0.19.0/lib/web3/function.js#L248-L258)

In Solidity, you need to mark your function with the `constant` keyword in order to generate an ABI where the function is marked `constant`.

### Web3.js v1 Beta

Based on the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12), it appears that contract methods will no longer be callable without specifying `call()` or `send()`.